# How to use c#.net EPPlus with Mono

Tags: .net, monodevelop, epplus

I've looked into ways of manipulating Excel files using c#.net without using the Excel interop and have come across EPPlus. It seems to work great on windows. But how can I get it to work in Mono (our server is a Linux server).

This is the code I tried just to test (a simple .exe):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
        ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = CreateSheet(excelPackage, "TestSheet");

        Byte[] bin = excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
        string file = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Test.xlsx";
        File.WriteAllBytes(file, bin);
    }
}
}
```

But of course when I try to run it from the Linux server it crashes and says "Console App has stopped working". Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This version does not support Mono. Please refer to [EPPlus FAQ](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ)

> **Can I use this library with Mono?**
>
> Good question! I haven't tried,so I have no idea. Please give me some feedback if you have tried.

Comment: That doesn't say "we don't support it", only "we haven't tried it".

Comment: Any luck? They didn't care whether EPPlus can work finely with Mono means they didn't intend to support Mono, hence, I recommended him not to use it with Mono.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!
Downloaded Epplus 4.0.3.
Created an excel workbook using libreoffice.
Created a console application using monodevelop on mint 17.1.

```
using System;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.IO;
namespace test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo ("tht.xlsx");
            using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage(f))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets["Ark1"];
                Console.WriteLine(ws.Cells[1, 1].Value);
            }


        }
    }
}
```